# ListenerAdapter changes Memory Adress randomly? - Discord JDA API

Tags: java, api, discord

So I just started playing around with [JDA API](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/index.html) trying to create a little /info command which looked like shown below.

**Issue:** Unfortunately the bot does not react when I type /info.

While I was debugging, I found out, that the **Info command never get's called** and I will explain why later, after showing you the 3 classes that are involved in this problem.

```
public class InfoCommand extends Command {
    public InfoCommand(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
    @Override
    public void handle(MessageReceivedEvent event, String... params) {
        EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder();
        builder.setTitle("Test Title");
        builder.setDescription("Test Description" );
        builder.setFooter("Created by t0gepi");
        builder.setColor(0xf45642);
        event.getChannel().sendTyping().queue();
        event.getChannel().sendMessageEmbeds(builder.build()).queue();
    }
}
```

It has a method **handle** which will be called by a **CommandManager**, whenever /info is typed in the discord server.
So far so good.

Now the **Main method** is also quite simple. It just starts the bot and adds the CommandManager as a Listener to JDA:

```
public class Main {
    public static JDA jda;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
        ResourceManager.init();
        jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(ResourceManager.getProperty("discord.bottoken")).build();
        jda.getPresence().setStatus(OnlineStatus.IDLE);
        jda.getPresence().setActivity(Activity.playing("Sleeping"));
        try {
            jda.awaitReady();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        CommandManager commandManager = new CommandManager();
        commandManager.addCommand(new InfoCommand("info"));
        jda.addEventListener(new CommandManager());
    }
}
```

Lastly, let's get to the CommandManager:

```
public class CommandManager extends ListenerAdapter {

    private Set<Command> commands;

    public CommandManager(){
        this.commands = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public void addCommand(Command command){
        commands.add(command);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NotNull MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        String[] msg = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");
        String prefix = ResourceManager.getProperty("command.prefix");
        String[] params = null;
        if(!msg[0].startsWith(prefix)){
            return;
        }
        if(msg.length > 1){
            params = Arrays.copyOfRange(msg,1,msg.length);
        }
        Iterator<Command> iterator = commands.iterator();
        Command command;
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            command = iterator.next();
            if(command.getAliases().stream().anyMatch(alias -> msg[0].equalsIgnoreCase(prefix + alias))){
                command.handle(event, params);
                return;
            }
        }
        // Do nothing here if command wasn't found.
    }
}
```

Now let's get to the actual issue, why does the InfoCommands handle method not get called? Keep in mind that

- InfoCommand has bin initialized and added to the CommandManager
- The CommandManagers onMessageReceived method is in fact being called when a message is typed

As I was debugging, I found out why but could not find an explanation to it.

The reason why the handle method of InfoCommand does not get called, is because as to the time when onMessageReceived gets called, the CommandManagers **set of commands is empty**.

Why is that? I added the InfoCommand in the beginning right?

When I added the InfoCommand in the **beginning**, the set of commands had a **size of 1**. All good. But **when onMessageReceived got called**, the set of Commands suddenly had a **size of 0**, which means that the Iterator doesn't have anything to iterate over.

Why is that? I furthermore found out the following:

As to the time where I initialized the CommandManager, the CommandManager had a **different memory adress** than when it's onMessageReceived method got called.

So somehow, JDA must have created another new instance of CommandManager and used that, instead of my instance, right?

I hope someone understands this and let me know if you have any questions :)
Thanks for reading that far and if you'd like, you can take a better look at all the files in this Project [here](https://github.com/t0gepi/JeremyBot). There really aren't much more.

Comment: Please don't add things like SOLVED to a question title. If you managed to solve the problem, add an answer explaining the solution and accept it after the timeout. As an aside, the answer you have posted right now is not considered an actual answer. It might be better to just delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of your command manager when you register it:

```java
jda.addEventListener(new CommandManager());
```

Instead, you should just pass in the instance you previously created:

```java
CommandManager commandManager = new CommandManager();
commandManager.addCommand(new InfoCommand("info"));
jda.addEventListener(commandManager);
```